# Is moon in perfect tidal lock with earth?

Tags: orbital-motion, earth, moon, tidal-effect

Moon appears to be facing its same side to earth throughout its orbit around earth.

This is said to be because of tidal locking , i.e. the moon rotates at the same rate as it revolves around the earth.

But how close does it rotation and revolution periods match? Are they 100% equal? It could be rotating say a millionth of a degree each year with respect to earth

Is it possible that there is a slight difference and in a million years we'll see a different side of the moon

Comment: The terms you are using in the question seem to be "simplified" compared with the real situation. Since the moon's orbit is not a perfect circle, and it is perturbed by the sun's gravity, it doesn't have *exactly* the "same side" facing the earth at all times. Also, the ocean tides on earth are slowly removing kinetic energy from the moon, and its "orbit" is really a spiral, increasing in radius by about 38mm per year, and its orbital period is slowly increasing. So the question as you asked it doesn't really have a simple "yes/no" answer.

Comment: Well my question simply is will we ever see a different face of the moon from earth in say a next billion years

Answer (score 4):

> **Is it possible that there is a slight difference and in a million years we'll see a different side of the moon**

No.

Tidal locking is a process that drains energy from the rotation of the moon. The moon's shape is distorted by the gravitational attraction. This means to draw the moon out of a tidally locked state would require it to move into a configuration that is more energetic - I don't think there is a source for the additional energy required.

It is as if the moon had rolled to the bottom of a valley. Now that it is at rest there, it would require a lot of energy to roll it back up the hillside.

Also, if the moon has been tidally locked for billions of years, a million years seems too short an interval of time for anything interesting to happen.